# HttpContext.AuthenticateAsync do not return "sub" claim after update to .NET 8

Tags: c#, authentication, hangfire, .net-8.0

After I updated our solution from .NET 6 to .NET 8 and `Hangfire.AspNetCore` to version 1.8.6, we can't access our Hangfire dashboard anymore. When I revert to an old branch with .NET 6, there's no problem.

I was able to find the difference between the .NET 8 and .NET 6 branches, and it is in the dashboard middleware. I have the following method in the middleware that authenticates with a cookie scheme, takes the logged user, signs in, and signs out with the cookie scheme:

```cs
private async Task LoginCallback(HttpContext httpContext)
{
    var result = await httpContext.AuthenticateAsync(options.CookieAuthenticationScheme + ".external");

    if (result?.Succeeded != true)
    {
        throw new Exception("external login failed");
    }

    var token = new JwtSecurityToken(result.Properties.GetTokenValue("access_token"));

    var claims = Enumerable.Concat(
        result.Principal.Claims.Where(c => c.Type == "sub"),
        token.Claims.Where(c => new[] { "tid", "tname", "scope" }.Contains(c.Type))
    );

    var claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, options.CookieAuthenticationScheme);
    var authProperties = new AuthenticationProperties();

    logger.LogInformation("External authentication of {Subject} to Hangfire Dashboard.", claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == "sub")?.Value);
    await httpContext.SignInAsync(options.CookieAuthenticationScheme, new ClaimsPrincipal(claimsIdentity), authProperties);
    await httpContext.SignOutAsync(options.CookieAuthenticationScheme + ".external");
}
```

When this method is invoked, the logger message is

> External authentication of null to Hangfire Dashboard. <s:STP.IM.WorkflowProcess.Auth.HangfireDashboard.HangfireDashboardAuthenticationMiddleware>

This means that the

```
claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == "sub")?.Value
```

did not find any value, and then the

```
httpContext.SignInAsync(options.CookieAuthenticationScheme, new ClaimsPrincipal(claimsIdentity), authProperties);
```

call does not sign the user in.

I then spotted a difference in the `result.Principal.Claims` `IEnumerable`: in the .NET 6 branch, I have an entry of type "sub" with a value that looks to me like an Guid. In the .NET 8 branch this entry is missing.

I guess that there are some changes made in the .NET 8 regarding authentication, because the `httpContext.AuthenticateAsync` does not return that claim with a "sub" type.

Is there a way this problem can be fixed?

Thanks in advance

***SOLUTION***:
In my `Startup.cs` in the `ConfigureServices` I've added:

```cs
Microsoft.IdentityModel.JsonWebTokens.JsonWebTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap.Clear();
```